# PostgreSQL frontend unexpectedly closes connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm a little bit confused with the following case.

I've got a `Postgres` server running on host A, and a java based client running on host B. The client uses `org.postgresql.Driver` JDBC driver (version 9.1-901.jdbc3).

sometimes while executing long running stored procedure I get exception "`java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`". I'm using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` for retrieving 
connections.

DBCP pool is configured with default options.

I got tcp dump in order to figure out on which side (client or server) socket is being closed;

Here is what I've got:

```
1.   Client B sends a test query message when tries to borrow connection from dbcp pool ("Select 1")
2.   Server A sends successful response back (Type: Command completion, Ready for query)
3.   Client B sends ACK message in response on server A response (see the item 2).
4.   Client B sends query message to the server A.
5.   Server A sends ACK message in response on client Query message (see the item 4).
6.   Client B sends terminating message (Type : Termination) after some time passed (from 3 to 10 or sometimes even more minutes).
7    Client B sends FIN ACK message to the server.
8.   Server A sends back ACK on termination message.
9.   Server A sends ACK on (FIN, ACK) message (item 7).
10.  Server A sends back a response on the client query (from item 4) Type: Row description Columns: 40.
11.  Client B sends RST message (reset).
12.  Server A continues sending response on the query Type: Data row Length: 438 Columns 40 and so on.
13   Client B sends RST message (reset) again.
14.  Server A continues sending response on the query Type: Data row Length: 438 Columns 40 and so on.
15.  Client B sends RST message (reset).
```

After that communication seems to be finished.

After the item 6, in my client logs I got Exception like the following:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:145)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:114)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:274)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1661)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
```

Could you please help me to figure out the reason of such a failure. (This bug happens once per 10 successful cases.)

Comment: What, if anything, appears in the PostgreSQL error logs? Consider restarting PostgreSQL with `log_min_messages = debug3` for detailed, verbose (and huge) logs. You'll want an appropriate `log_line_prefix` so you can tell which session is which. Also, PostgreSQL version? (`SELECT version()`). Finally, what's the network like between client and server? How many hops? Internet, or only LAN? WiFi involved? any NAT, firewalls, proxies, connection tracking routers?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and it was caused by a firewall or connection tracking router between the server and the client.

I am guessing you took the tcpdump on the server side. The query runs for a considerable time with no traffic on the connection. The firewall has a timer on the open connection; it expires and the firewall closes the connection towards the server, and also back towards the client. On the capture at the server side, it looks like the client is closing the connection.

You could verify this by capturing on the client side simultaneously as you capture on the server side - on the client side it will look like the server has closed the connection, while on the server side it looks like the server is closing the connection. In reality the firewall is closing it in both directions.

To prevent this, you can set [tcp_keepalives_idle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE), [tcp_keepalives_interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-INTERVAL) and/or [tcp_keepalives_count](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-COUNT) (if your OS supports TCP Keepalives). Alternatively, you will have to change the settings on the firewall.